# "date" command doesn't show many timezones on Centos 8

Tags: centos, date, timezone

On a fresh Centos 8 system, the `date` command does not show many timezones even though the timezone is properly set by `timedatectl` and `/etc/localtime` points to the correct TZ data file.

For example:

```
# timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Tokyo
# date
Thu May  7 19:18:34 JST 2020

# timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Singapore
# ls -ld /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 May  7 18:16 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore
# date
Thu May  7 18:18:18 +08 2020
```

In the first case "JST" is properly displayed, but the second case shows "+08" instead of "SGT".

Timezone names were shown properly in Centos 6.  Is there an additional package I need to install?

**EDIT I**

As requested by *binarysta*, I tried specifying "Singapore" directly.  No joy.

```
# timedatectl set-timezone Singapore
# date
Thu May  7 20:52:53 +08 2020
# ls -ld /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 May  7 20:52 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Singapore
```

In fact, a lot of timezones are reported only with the numeric offset.  I ran a script on the contents of `/etc/zoneinfo/Asia` and got 70 timezones with this problem...

```
Aden  Thu May  7 16:06:44 +03 2020
Almaty  Thu May  7 19:06:44 +06 2020
Anadyr  Fri May  8 01:06:44 +12 2020
Aqtau  Thu May  7 18:06:44 +05 2020
Aqtobe  Thu May  7 18:06:44 +05 2020
Ashgabat  Thu May  7 18:06:44 +05 2020
Ashkhabad  Thu May  7 18:06:44 +05 2020
Atyrau  Thu May  7 18:06:44 +05 2020
Baghdad  Thu May  7 16:06:44 +03 2020
Bahrain  Thu May  7 16:06:44 +03 2020
Baku  Thu May  7 17:06:44 +04 2020
Bangkok  Thu May  7 20:06:44 +07 2020
Barnaul  Thu May  7 20:06:44 +07 2020
Bishkek  Thu May  7 19:06:44 +06 2020
Brunei  Thu May  7 21:06:44 +08 2020
Chita  Thu May  7 22:06:44 +09 2020
Choibalsan  Thu May  7 21:06:44 +08 2020
Colombo  Thu May  7 18:36:44 +0530 2020
Dacca  Thu May  7 19:06:44 +06 2020
Dhaka  Thu May  7 19:06:44 +06 2020
Dili  Thu May  7 22:06:44 +09 2020
Dubai  Thu May  7 17:06:44 +04 2020
Dushanbe  Thu May  7 18:06:44 +05 2020
Ho_Chi_Minh  Thu May  7 20:06:44 +07 2020
Hovd  Thu May  7 20:06:44 +07 2020
Irkutsk  Thu May  7 21:06:44 +08 2020
Istanbul  Thu May  7 16:06:44 +03 2020
Kabul  Thu May  7 17:36:44 +0430 2020
Kamchatka  Fri May  8 01:06:44 +12 2020
Kashgar  Thu May  7 19:06:44 +06 2020
Kathmandu  Thu May  7 18:51:44 +0545 2020
Katmandu  Thu May  7 18:51:44 +0545 2020
Khandyga  Thu May  7 22:06:44 +09 2020
Krasnoyarsk  Thu May  7 20:06:44 +07 2020
Kuala_Lumpur  Thu May  7 21:06:44 +08 2020
Kuching  Thu May  7 21:06:44 +08 2020
Kuwait  Thu May  7 16:06:44 +03 2020
Magadan  Fri May  8 00:06:44 +11 2020
Muscat  Thu May  7 17:06:44 +04 2020
Novokuznetsk  Thu May  7 20:06:44 +07 2020
Novosibirsk  Thu May  7 20:06:44 +07 2020
Omsk  Thu May  7 19:06:44 +06 2020
Oral  Thu May  7 18:06:44 +05 2020
Phnom_Penh  Thu May  7 20:06:44 +07 2020
Qatar  Thu May  7 16:06:44 +03 2020
Qostanay  Thu May  7 19:06:44 +06 2020
Qyzylorda  Thu May  7 18:06:44 +05 2020
Rangoon  Thu May  7 19:36:44 +0630 2020
Riyadh  Thu May  7 16:06:44 +03 2020
Saigon  Thu May  7 20:06:44 +07 2020
Sakhalin  Fri May  8 00:06:44 +11 2020
Samarkand  Thu May  7 18:06:44 +05 2020
Singapore  Thu May  7 21:06:44 +08 2020
Srednekolymsk  Fri May  8 00:06:44 +11 2020
Tashkent  Thu May  7 18:06:44 +05 2020
Tbilisi  Thu May  7 17:06:44 +04 2020
Tehran  Thu May  7 17:36:44 +0430 2020
Thimbu  Thu May  7 19:06:44 +06 2020
Thimphu  Thu May  7 19:06:44 +06 2020
Tomsk  Thu May  7 20:06:44 +07 2020
Ulaanbaatar  Thu May  7 21:06:44 +08 2020
Ulan_Bator  Thu May  7 21:06:44 +08 2020
Urumqi  Thu May  7 19:06:44 +06 2020
Ust-Nera  Thu May  7 23:06:44 +10 2020
Vientiane  Thu May  7 20:06:44 +07 2020
Vladivostok  Thu May  7 23:06:44 +10 2020
Yakutsk  Thu May  7 22:06:44 +09 2020
Yangon  Thu May  7 19:36:44 +0630 2020
Yekaterinburg  Thu May  7 18:06:44 +05 2020
Yerevan  Thu May  7 17:06:44 +04 2020
```

**EDIT II**

The response from [aniskh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/266771/aniskh) was helpful, who said the timezone data "is provided by the tzdata package, so the output of date will depend on this package".

The timezone names were present in Centos 6 but not in Centos 8.  So that would point to a bug within the `tzdata` package?

Centos 6:

```
$ zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore  Fri May 15 08:25:58 2020 SGT
$ yum list installed | grep tz
tzdata.noarch                         2015d-1.el6                      installed
tzdata-java.noarch                    2015d-1.el6                      installed
```

Centos 8:

```
$ zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore  Fri May 15 08:52:30 2020 +08
$ yum list installed | grep tz
tzdata.noarch                        2019c-1.el8                            @anaconda
tzdata-java.noarch                   2019c-1.el8                            @AppStream
```

Comment: could you please check with the singapore in the zoneinfo directory? not the one in Asia directory, `ls /usr/share/zoneinfo/Singapore` use `timedatectl set-timezone Singapore`

Comment: `ls -l /usr/share/zoneinfo/Singapore` show it is just a symlink to `ls -l /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore`. So using `timedatectl set-timezone Singapore` is the same as `timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Singapore`

Answer (score 1):

`date` command gets the name from the timezone data file `/etc/localtime` pointing to a file in the directory `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`. When reading the content of the **Singapore** timezone, you can see that the **name of the timezone** is **+08** whereas the name of the timezone for **Asia/Tokyo** is **JST**:

(`zdump` command is a timezone dumper)

```
$ zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore 
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore  Thu May 14 06:53:21 2020 +08

$ zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo 
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo  Thu May 14 07:53:31 2020 JST
```

These files are provided by `tzdata` package, so the output of `date` will depend on this package .

Comment: That's very useful.  Above, I've added the difference between Centos 6 vs 8.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority) changed the timezone naming policy for a number of countries in 2017.  I guess these changes were reflected in the `tzdata` database, and propagated to the rpms.

Reading the [IANA Timezones News Page](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdb/NEWS):

> Release 2017a - 2017-02-28 00:05:36 -0800
>
> [ ... ]
>
> Changes to past and future time zone abbreviations
>
> Switch to numeric time zone abbreviations for South America, as part
>   of the ongoing project of removing invented abbreviations. This avoids
>   the need to invent an abbreviation for the new Chilean new zone. 
>   Similarly, switch from invented to numeric time zone abbreviations for
>   Afghanistan, American Samoa, the Azores, Bangladesh, Bhutan, the
>   British Indian Ocean Territory, Brunei, Cape Verde, Chatham Is,
>   Christmas I, Cocos (Keeling) Is, Cook Is, Dubai, East Timor, Eucla,
>   Fiji, French Polynesia, Greenland, Indochina, Iran, Iraq, Kiribati,
>   Lord Howe, Macquarie, Malaysia, the Maldives, Marshall Is, Mauritius,
>   Micronesia, Mongolia, Myanmar, Nauru, Nepal, New Caledonia, Niue,
>   Norfolk I, Palau, Papua New Guinea, the Philippines, Pitcairn, Qatar,
>   Réunion, St Pierre & Miquelon, Samoa, Saudi Arabia, Seychelles,
>   **Singapore**, Solomon Is, Tokelau, Tuvalu, Wake, Vanuatu, Wallis &
>   Futuna, and Xinjiang; for 20-minute daylight saving time in Ghana
>   before 1943; for half-hour daylight saving time in Belize before 1944
>   and in the Dominican Republic before 1975; and for Canary Islands
>   before 1946, for Guinea-Bissau before 1975, for Iceland before 1969,
>   for Indian Summer Time before 1942, for Indonesia before around 1964,
>   for Kenya before 1960, for Liberia before 1973, for Madeira before
>   1967, for Namibia before 1943, for the Netherlands in 1937-9, for
>   Pakistan before 1971, for Western Sahara before 1977, and for
>   Zaporozhye in 1880-1924.